# Locking a call until other call is complete

Tags: go

Hello I have this code in a go func

```
as.client, err = getConnection(hostname, port))
if err != nil {
    return nil, err
}

as.session, err = as.client.NewSession()
if err != nil {
    return nil, err
}
```

Unfortunately it seems to be erroring out because it is starting to call NewSession before the client is created. I can add a time.Sleep in between these calls and that fixes it, but is there a better way to use a mutex or callback function here? How would I do that?

Comment: Is this `getConnection` function something that returns before completely initializing the value it returned? If that's the case, you need to fix that.

Comment: It is a third party library @BurakSerdar

Comment: It is an unexported function in the code you posted, so you either have a wrapper around it or you didn't post the actual code. In any case, `getConnection` should not return a value and continue setting it up in a separate goroutine, or should give you a way to check completion. Without these,  there is a data race around `as.client`, the behavior is undefined, and there is no reliable way to fix it.

Comment: We cannot see enough code here to really identify and solve the problem, but consider using `sync.Once` to run some third party function once, while making every caller wait until that function has run to completion once.

Answer (score 1):

Using mutex or a callback here would be an over-complicated hack.

To avoid confusion and data races the `getConnection` should return the control only after it's done setting its return values. If this is a third party library, there should be a documentation explaining why it doesn't do that and perhaps providing some cues how to correctly use the function.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things you could do here.

1. Make `getConnection()` synchronous i.e., it returns control only once the client is created. You can use [`sync.WaitGroup`](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/) to block within this function.
2. `getConnection()` could also return a channel and post something on
   that channel once it is done. The caller can then read from the
   channel to block itself until the client is created.